# JavaScript - Pixastic - Error : this operation is unsecure

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, pixastic

I'm trying to desaturate an image using Pixastic. I donwloaded the script from the official  [website](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/download/) and checked the only things needed (core, jquery plugin, and desaturate effect).

I tried using the same code as they show in the demo, except that i enclosed it inside the .ready function of jQuery, but this isn't supposed to cause problems :

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            // document.body.appendChild(img); // Ialso tried putting this here.
            Pixastic.process(img, "desaturate", {average : false});
        };
        document.body.appendChild(img);
        img.src = "http://127.0.0.1/some_path/Wallpapers/ (10).jpg"; // This URL does point to the image file.
    });
})(window.jQuery);
```

But i always get the same error : This operation is unsecure.
The error comes from the Pixastic js file at line 374 :

```
prepareData : function(params, getCopy) {
            var ctx = params.canvas.getContext("2d");
            var rect = params.options.rect;
            var dataDesc = ctx.getImageData(rect.left, rect.top, rect.width, rect.height); // 374
            var data = dataDesc.data;
            if (!getCopy) params.canvasData = dataDesc;
            return data;
        },
```

I'm developing on a local wamp server.

Any idea about what i'm doing wrong ?
Thanks for your help ! :)

Comment: what url do you use to navigate to your server? does it match your `127.0.0.1` in the code? can you use a relative url in the code?

Comment: I'm typing localhost in the adress bar and then browse to my index.php file.
Here is the URL displayed in the address bar : `http://localhost/Workspace/VoidMuseum/v2/`

Comment: try using a relative url for the image.

Comment: YAAA ! You've put me on the right way ! I needed to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem :

I had to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in the browser address bar. If someone knows the exact reason, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 1):

the URL for the image in the code must match the URL that you use to serve the pages from. I would use a relative URL in the code. If the image comes from a different domain then the server that serves the image must support CORS (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for this to work.

Comment: Found the solution. It seems to be as you said : localhost != 127.0.0.1. Thanks for the extra details.